# Multiple Batteries infomation python

Tags: python

I have a lenovo thinkpad T570, which has two batteries.
I would like to make a python program that uses info about the seperate batteries.
But I dont know how to return infomation about each battery seperately.

I have tried using psutil and psutil.sensors_battery.percent(), but it returns the average battery percentage of the two batteries.

Comment: I'm not sure that this information is going to be exposed like that, as having two separate batteries is not something I even expected to be a thing in 2023. I haven't heard of that since the old PowerBook from the 1990s that could swap the CD drive for an additional battery.

Comment: the laptop has a build-in battery and a removable battery

Comment: I get that. I'm just saying it's an edge case, as the overwhelming majority of laptops do not have this feature.

Comment: thank you for your help tadman, I understand the issue in helping me. I found a program native to Lenovo computers that had the functionality I was looking for